# Make rectangle jump in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I have created a game in which the user should be able to press the space button to jump (which will go up and then down after a certain time) but when it runs, it automatically updates to just show the final position, not the actual jump itself. I tried pygame.time.wait(). However, I still face the same problem. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

```
    xcoor=(0)the leader of the group of blocks
    ycoor=(550)
    while not gameExit:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                ycoor = 500
                ycoor = 550 
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, purple,[xcoor,ycoor,50,50])
```

Comment: don't use `wait`, `sleep` or any similar. you have to set variable `jump=True` and then increase coordinate in every loop till it get `500` and then you set `jump=False`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set variable ie. `jump = True` and increase `ycoor` in every loop till you get 500.

More or less like this

```
xcoor = 0 #the leader of the group of blocks
ycoor = 550

jump = False
fall = False

while not gameExit:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                if not fall:
                    jump = True

    if jump:
        ycoor += 5
        if ycoor >= 500:
            ycoor = 500
            jump = False
            fall = True

    if fall:
        ycoor -= 5
        if ycoor <= 0:
            ycoor = 0
            fall = False

    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, purple,[xcoor,ycoor,50,50])
```